# How can i change how quickly my screen goes off Nikon D3300

Tags: dslr, nikon-d3300

I find it really annoying when i am looking at my settings or whatever and the screen goes blank too quickly, how can i change this??

Comment: Does your *User Manual* say anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Auto Off timer menu, in the Setup menu.

It is page 245 in the D3300 REFERENCE MANUAL.

The **Reference manual** is a more complete manual, MUCH larger than the User Manual. Available free from http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/21/D3300.html   and recommended.